# WCF discovery doesn't work between two computers on the same subnet with the firewall turned off

Tags: c#, wcf

This simple WCF discovery example works on a single machine but when the client and server are running on separate machines in the same subnet with no firewall, it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Discovery;

namespace WCFDiscovery
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         try { if (args.Length > 0) StartClient(); else StartServer(); }
         catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }
         finally { Console.WriteLine("press enter to quit..."); Console.ReadLine(); }
      }

      private static void StartServer()
      {
         var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).First(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
         var address = new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:3702", ipAddress));
         var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), address);
         host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new NetTcpBinding(), address);
         host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
         host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
         host.Open();
         Console.WriteLine("Started on {0}", address);
      }

      private static void StartClient()
      {
         var dc = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
         Console.WriteLine("Searching for service...");
         var findResponse = dc.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(IService)));
         var response = ChannelFactory<IService>.CreateChannel(new NetTcpBinding(), findResponse.Endpoints[0].Address).Add(1, 2);
         Console.WriteLine("Service response: {0}", response);
      }
   }

   [ServiceContract] interface IService { [OperationContract] int Add(int x, int y); }

   class Service : IService { public int Add(int x, int y) { return x + y; } }
}
```

Comment: _"when the client and server are running on separate machines"_ - do you use a different address then? Also: _"it doesn't work"_ is not an exception. Show the exact message.

Comment: The server listens on port 8000. By "doesn't work" I mean that "dc.Find(...)" returns zero endpoints so this code "Endpoints[0]" throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Does it make any difference if you change "localhost" to the IP address of your server that your client will be connecting to?

Comment: I updated the code above to not hard code "localhost" but the result was the same.

Comment: can you perform the telnet test from one machine to the other? ie, what happens when you try `telnet <server> 3702`
you should get a blank window indicating the port is open. (or a trying... msg if the port is not reachable)
Also, i'm pretty certain using localhost isnt your issue (as you figured out) - now u mention port 8000 in your comments but use port 3702 in your code?

Comment: Yes, the telnet test passes. While connecting from the client machine to the server machine, the telnet client shows a blank window indicating the port is open. Also, I changed to port 3702 just to make sure that didn't solve the problem after reading this: "...multicast messages are sent to port 3702." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd352335(v=bts.10).aspx

Comment: +1 for self-contained code example, btw. A good example on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run your code on 2 different machines (notebook (Win7) and tower PC (Win8), .NET FW 4.5, same WiFi network) and received following exception:

```
A remote side security requirement was not fulfilled during authentication. Try increasing the ProtectionLevel and/or ImpersonationLevel.
```

This one is due to the service security being underspecified, the endpoint were found. So, the guys in other answers are right - this is a network problem which can't be fixed by correcting code.
I'd add that another possible source of the problem may be the network switch not permitting UDP broadcasts.

Comment: Turns out the network switch was not permitting UDP broadcasts. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, is the windows firewall also turned off?

Also make sure you're binding your server to an address that the other computer uses to communicate with it.

Localhost or 127.0.0.1 will likely not pick up a connection to its externally(to the host) addressable IP which is what the multicast discovery packets would arrive on.

[MSDN instructions on turning the windows firewall off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751530.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I manually turned off the firewall on both machines in Control Panel and it doesn't work. Both machines are Windows 7 with .NET 4.0

Comment: I updated the code above to not hard code "localhost" but the result was the same.

Comment: Does your router have a separate firewall that could be blocking this port? Might want to look into port forwarding if this is the case.

Comment: I've confirmed that the port is open using telnet so I don't believe the firewall is the issue.